# Imported global variable from dll not updated

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

I am exporting a global variable from a dll using __declspec(dllexport) and importing the same in the client exe using __declspec(dllimport).

The global variable in the dll is being updated with time in a separate thread. I want to receive this updated data in my client .exe, but I am not getting it. What I get is the only initial value of the global variable every time I read the data using a timer in the client exe.

What is the explanation of such a behavior? and what can I do to achieve what I want to achieve? Is there an option without including get() and set() exported functions from the dll?

Here is the code that is exported from dll:

```
typedef struct{
    int iTotalQueues;
    int iCurrentQueue;
    wchar_t szQueueName[100];
}UPDATE_STATUS_DATA;

__declspec(dllexport) UPDATE_STATUS_DATA UpdateStatusData;
```

This structure members are updated in a loop for a long time. The updating code is in the dll itself.

Here is the code that is imported in the exe:

```
typedef struct{
    int iTotalQueues;
    int iCurrentQueue;
    wchar_t szQueueName[100];
}UPDATE_STATUS_DATA;

__declspec(dllimport) UPDATE_STATUS_DATA UpdateStatusData;
```

I am reading this data inside a timer response and not getting the updated values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question as you would expect when built into a simple test project. So, here are the two explanations that I can concoct:

1. You are taking a copy of `UpdateStatusData` in your executable. And so the changes to the value of `UpdateStatusData` made in the DLL do not get reflected in the copy.
2. Your DLL is, for some reason, not modifying the struct.